# Literal array notation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, literals

Sorry for maybe stupid question, I am a very beginner.
In some test code for iOS I see:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = cellsArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
```

How can I spell out right part of this statement?
Thanks for help!

Comment: What do you mean by spell out right?

Comment: I understand that I am receiving a cell as a result(left part of statement), but what with the right part? Is this a link to say, object with appropriate indexPath.section and indexPath.row?

Comment: Subscript access to arrays and dictionaries using this syntax is, I believe, a recent addition. NSHipster has a nice overview on the whole thing http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an exact equivalent of:

```
[[cellsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

cellsArray is an array of arrays, a 2-dimensional array. its count is number of sections in table view. every array represents a section and contains cells for this section. so you can access each cell by its row

Comment: Thanks, now it's understood! Because I am less of karma to vote up and accept your answer, I'll do this as quick as it will be possible

Answer (score 3):

you have to make 2D array:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[cellsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```